# Cannot find "2 rules never reduce" and "conflicts: 2 shift/reduce" in yacc file

Tags: bison, yacc, context-free-grammar

I cannot seem to find the above errors when I am trying to "compile" my yacc file. I am hoping someone can point out the lines and let me know what I would need to do to correct the problem(s). I have listed my file:

```
%token Identifier Int Real_Num And Array
%token Begin Boolean Div Do Else
%token End False For Goto If
%token Imply Integer Label Not Or
%token Own Procedure Real Step String
%token Then True Until Value While
%token Plus Minus Mult Divide Less
%token LessEq Great GreatEq Eq NotEq
%token Comma Colon Semi LParan RParan
%token LBrak RBrak Assign

%{

%}

%start program

%%

program
        : block
        ;

block
        : Begin optdecls stmts End
        ;

optdecls
        : /* empty */
        | decl Comma optdecls
        ;

decl
        : vardecl
        | arraydecl
        ;

vardecl
        : type idlist
        ;

type
        : Real
        | Integer
        | Boolean
        ;

idlist
        : Identifier
        | Identifier Comma idlist
        ;

arraydecl
        : Array arraylist
        | type Array arraylist
        ;

arraylist
        : arrayseg
        | arrayseg Comma arraylist
        ;

arrayseg
        : Identifier LBrak a_expr Colon a_expr RBrak

stmts
        : stmt
        | stmt Semi stmts
        ;

stmt
        : u_stmt
        | if_stmt
        | for_stmt
        ;

u_stmt
        : assign
        | dummy
        | block
        ;

assign
        : var Assign expr
        | var Assign assign
        ;

dummy
        : /* empty */
        ;

for_stmt
        : For var Assign a_expr Step a_expr Until a_expr Do stmt
        ;

if_stmt
        : If expr Then u_stmt
        | If expr Then u_stmt Else stmt
        | If expr Then for_stmt
        ;

var
        : Identifier
        | Identifier LBrak a_expr RBrak
        ;

factor
        : Int
        | Real_Num
        | var
        | LParan expr RParan
        ;

term
        : factor
        | term Mult factor
        | term Divide factor
        | term Div factor
        ;

sum
        : term
        | Plus term
        | Minus term
        | sum Plus term
        | sum Minus term
        ;

brel
        : sum
        | True
        | False
        | sum relation sum
        ;

relation
        : Less
        | LessEq
        | Great
        | GreatEq
        | Eq
        | NotEq
        ;

bsecond
        : brel
        | Not brel
        ;

bfactor
        : bsecond
        | bfactor And bsecond
        ;

bterm
        : bfactor
        | bterm Or bfactor
        ;

expr
        : bterm
        | If expr Then bterm Else expr
        ;

a_expr
        : sum
        | If expr Then sum Else a_expr
        ;

%%
```

Sorry for the long post but I believe the coded all of the code is relevant. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-v` option to `bison`, which will generate a .output file with information on all the states and conflicts.  With you grammar, this gives conflicts in states 16 and 30.

State 16 is:

```
state 16

   15 arraylist: arrayseg .
   16          | arrayseg . Comma arraylist

    Comma  shift, and go to state 34

    Comma  [reduce using rule 15 (arraylist)]
```

Which is telling you that it doesn't know whether to shift the Comma after seeing an `arrayseg` in order to parse more `arraylist`, or if it should reduce the `arraylist` and allow the Comma to be part of some other rule (such as `optdecls`) that allows for a Comma after an arraylist.

State 30 is:

```
state 30

   11 idlist: Identifier .
   12       | Identifier . Comma idlist

    Comma  shift, and go to state 59

    Comma  [reduce using rule 11 (idlist)]
```

which is basically the same thing.

The essential problem is that your grammar describes comma-separated lists of things that contain comma separated lists, so it needs more lookahead to determine if the commas belong to the inner list or the outer list.

Perhaps you should have `Semi` rather than `Comma` between decls?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the grammar. So I guess what else can be done?